# Chrome Issue Google Map Api Jquery Is not Loading

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I have implemented Simple Google Map Direction Api Javascript in my webpage. When my Destinaion loaded from database, it will draw a map directly from this google api. But here in google chrome map cant be loaded, it is showing me some error kind of Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/HTMl. Can someone please bring me out from this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail. Reduced sample code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DirectionsRequests

Comment: From this i have implemented a google direction api, in which i have inserted waypoints using MS Sql Database. I have used the map in Jquery UI Tab. so when i load the map tab, it is showing me some error like image is truncated or corrupted from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i6669&2i1598&2e1&3u4&4m2&1u700&2u400&5m3&1e0&2b1&5sen-US&token=100221 something like this error. when i double click on this map error increasing always. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was another jQuery disturbing.
now i got solution.